# Jquery .attr() a number to the end of all id's

Tags: jquery

I am trying to attribute a number after each id's td's in a table.
I would need the ids to stay as they are but each time a table is cloned, a new number is set after each ID.

here is a fiddle that should help understanding my problem.

```
.find('td').attr('id', '_'+ newNum)
```

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/c4ynzm9w/1/)

the new id's should look like this

```
id="td01_2"
```

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
newElem.find('td').attr('id', '_'+ newNum);
```

to:

```
newElem.find('td').attr('id', function () {
    return this.id + '_' + newNum
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c4ynzm9w/2/)**

This will give your cloned td's the correct new IDs by taking the existing cloned ID (ex: `td01`) and adding `_` and `newNum`.

Ex:

```
<tr>
    <td id="td01_2">td 01</td>
    <td id="td02_2">td 02</td>
    <td id="td03_2">td 03</td>
    <td id="td04_2">td 04</td>
    <td id="td05_2">td 05</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I added a global counter var tdNum. then just append it to the id.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var tdNum=0;
  $('#add_button').click(function () {
      var num = $('.datatable_class').length;
      var newNum = num + 1;
      tdNum++;
      var newElem = $('#input1').clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum).removeClass('HiddenInput').addClass('.NewInputs').fadeIn( 1000 );
      newElem.find('td').attr('id', 'td'+tdNum+'_'+ newNum);
      $('#input' + num).after(newElem);  
   });
```

});